# Join two SQL Queries to produce one table without headings

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have made two `SQL` queries both bring back the information i want which is great, i was wondering if i could combine the `result` into one instead of 2 separate results , i don't know if this can be done but either show without headings or new custom headings.

the `SQL` code i am using is below

```
SELECT  T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ENERGY_KJ ,T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_PROTEIN, T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C_NETPRICE
FROM ((T_PRODUCT
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION ON T_PRODUCT.C_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION = T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ID)
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION ON T_PRODUCT.C_SELLING = T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C__OWNER_)
WHERE C_CODE LIKE 'STK000832';


SELECT  T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ENERGY_KJ ,T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_CARBOHYDRATESOFWHICHARESUGAR, T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C_NETPRICE
FROM ((T_PRODUCT
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION ON T_PRODUCT.C_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION = T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ID)
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION ON T_PRODUCT.C_SELLING = T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C__OWNER_)
WHERE C_CODE LIKE 'STK000832';
```

the result is below

[image]

below is the result i am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT  T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ENERGY_KJ AS NewHeading1,
T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_PROTEIN AS NewHeading2, 
T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C_NETPRICE AS NewHeading3
FROM ((T_PRODUCT
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION ON T_PRODUCT.C_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION = T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ID)
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION ON T_PRODUCT.C_SELLING = T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C__OWNER_)
WHERE C_CODE LIKE 'STK000832'
UNION ALL
SELECT  T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ENERGY_KJ AS NewHeading1,
T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_CARBOHYDRATESOFWHICHARESUGAR AS NewHeading2,
T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C_NETPRICE AS NewHeading3
FROM ((T_PRODUCT
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION ON T_PRODUCT.C_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION = T_PRODUCT_NUTRITIONALINFORMATION.C_ID)
INNER JOIN T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION ON T_PRODUCT.C_SELLING = T_PRODUCT_SELLING_PRICEDEFINITION.C__OWNER_)
WHERE C_CODE LIKE 'STK000832';
```